# Spring OAuth2 Authorization: Access Denied

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am pretty new to spring security & OAuth2. As a part of the learning I am trying to set up an **OAuth2 Authorization server** and **protect a REST end point** from unauthorized access.

My resource server contains couple of end points, with the following Authorization.

```
/products : only user with Authority='ROLE_PRODUCT_USER' and scope='read' can access this endpoint
/addProduct :  only user with Authority='ROLE_PRODUCT_ADMIN' and scope='write' can access this endpoint
```

> ISSUE: Access denied while trying to access the end points using
>   postman and grant_type="password"

**CODE**

> Resource Server

*ProductController.java*

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and hasAuthority('ROLE_PRODUCT_USER')")
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(productService.getAllProducts(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('write') and hasAuthority('ROLE_PRODUCT_ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping("/addproduct")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(productService.addProduct(product), HttpStatus.OK);
    }



}
```

*OAuth config in Resource Server*

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9090/user
```

> Authorization Server

*Main Class where the user-info-uri is implemented*

```
import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    @EnableResourceServer
    @RestController
    public class OAuthAuthorizationServerApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(OAuthAuthorizationServerApplication.class, args);
        }

        @GetMapping("/user")
        public Principal user(Principal user) {
            System.out.println(user);
            return user;
        }

    }
```

> Database
>   *oauth_client_details*

mysql> select * from oauth_client_details where client_id in ('reader','writer');

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-------------+
| client_id | resource_ids | client_secret                                                        | scope      | authorized_grant_types                                       | web_server_redirect_uri    | authorities        | access_token_validity | refresh_token_validity | additional_information | autoapprove |
+-----------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-------------+
| reader    | product_api  | {bcrypt}removed | read       | client_credentials,password,refersh_token,authorization_code | http://localhost:8080/home | ROLE_PRODUCT_USER  |                 10800 |                2592000 | NULL                   | NULL        |
| writer    | product_api  | {bcrypt}removed | read,write | client_credentials,password,refersh_token,authorization_code | http://localhost:8080/home | ROLE_PRODUCT_ADMIN |                 10800 |                2592000 | NULL                   | NULL        |
+-----------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-------------+
```

**ANALYSIS**

1. API works fine without Authorization
2. It works fine if we Authorize only with the Authority (@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('...')"))
3. Scope is missing (empty list) in the Authientication.OAuth2Request when it reaches,
        OAuth2ExpressionUtils --> hasAnyScope().
4. Scope is supplied from the /user endpoint of Authorization server

> {authorities=[{id=4, authority=ROLE_PRODUCT_USER}],
>   details={remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, sessionId=null,
>   tokenValue=2f54e499-e47a-45fe-a6f6-e4c9593f9841, tokenType=Bearer,
>   decodedDetails=null}, authenticated=true,
>   userAuthentication={authorities=[{id=4, authority=ROLE_PRODUCT_USER}],
>   details={clinet_id=reader, grant_type=password,
>   username=product_user}, authenticated=true, principal={password=null,
>   username=product_user, authorities=[{id=4,
>   authority=ROLE_PRODUCT_USER}], accountNonExpired=true,
>   accountNonLocked=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, enabled=true},
>   credentials=null, name=product_user}, credentials=,
>   oauth2Request={clientId=reader, **scope=[read]**,
>   requestParameters={clinet_id=reader, grant_type=password,
>   username=product_user}, resourceIds=[product_api],
>   authorities=[{authority=ROLE_PRODUCT_USER}], approved=true,
>   refresh=false, redirectUri=null, responseTypes=[], extensions={},
>   grantType=password, refreshTokenRequest=null},
>   principal={password=null, username=product_user, authorities=[{id=4,
>   authority=ROLE_PRODUCT_USER}], accountNonExpired=true,
>   accountNonLocked=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, enabled=true},
>   clientOnly=false, name=product_user}

5. But it is not persisted while creating an OAuth2Request in UserInfoTokenServices.extractAuthentication()

   ```
   private OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, Object> map) {
   Object principal = getPrincipal(map);
   List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = this.authoritiesExtractor
           .extractAuthorities(map);
   OAuth2Request request = new OAuth2Request(null, this.clientId, null, true, null,
           null, null, null, null);
   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
           principal, "N/A", authorities);
   token.setDetails(map);
   return new OAuth2Authentication(request, token);    }
   ```

Here the 5th paramter is a Set of string that represents scopes, which is passed as null!

> OAuth2Request request = new OAuth2Request(null, this.clientId, null,
>   true, null,
>                 null, null, null, null);

Am i missing any configuration here ?

Answer (score 2):

As you already noticed yourself and as mentioned in the [Issue #5096](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5096), the default `UserInfoTokenServices` does not support scopes, hence `#oauth2.hasScope` functionality. A possible solution would be to implement a custom `ResourceServerTokenServices`.

I also want to draw your attention to the fact that the [Spring Security OAuth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth#-deprecation-notice-) project is deprecated and is not recommended for use.

Comment: That is really a valuable information. Thanks a lot. I would refrain from using custom solutions and like to stick on to what spring is providing out of the box. What would be the best alternative if i want to create an Authorization server using spring boot?. Looks like i have reached a dead end when the migration document (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) says "Since Spring Security doesn’t provide Authorization Server support, migrating a Spring Security OAuth Authorization Server is out of scope for this document.".

Comment: Lots of document out there from spring and other sources which still talks about the OAuth2 Authorization Server!!. I wasted almost a month trying to understand it. Even the latest version of Spring Tool Suite did not gave any indication when i started using the OAuth2 project!.

Comment: @renjith there is currently no alternative to building an authorization server using Spring. I would advise you to consider other solutions, such as Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

@Renjith
Please refer to this question, I answered it there, let me know if u face any other challenges

[How to set user authorities from user claims return by an oauth server in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609083/how-to-set-user-authorities-from-user-claims-return-by-an-oauth-server-in-spring/63227874#63227874)

Another thing in your `@RestController`m use
this
`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_PRODUCT_USER')")` and not

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and hasAuthority('ROLE_PRODUCT_USER')")
```

Since the `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` is returning a list or set of `GrantedAuthority`, which your authorization server is returning the authenticated user authorities as ROLES, then you need to use the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_PRODUCT_USER')")` so it can use the `ROLES` prepend

Also refer to
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html

for more details on customizing the `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper`